# Coupons are applied but payment decting only one coupon in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, grand-total, order-totals

I'm using the Multiple coupons for magento2. in this module coupons are applied but amount is decting wrong. if I applied 2 coupons to the product those are applied when I pay the amount only one coupon amount is reduced.

example. product price is €239.96
I applied two coupons each one for € 30.00 total €60.00 reduced and the Grand total is €179.96

when I pay the amount is € 209,96 means only one coupon amount is dected.

below I attached the screenshot please check

[image]

in the network tab grand total and base grand total values are different

[image]

Comment: Did you check the module was compatible with your magento version? Did you follow the installation instructions given by the vendor? What's the vendor? Amasty?

Answer (score 1):

Magento by default doesn't support multiple coupons.

So maybe the problem lies in the 3rd-party extension you are using? Did you try contacting the developer/vendor?

Comment: I installed the 3rd party module in default magento2 but it is not working in the my project

Comment: I installed the 3rd party module in default magento2 but it is not working in the my project